Understanding the working of the common source transimpedance amplifier
I am trying to understand how a common source tia works (see the attached image). Referencing the image, can I assume the nmos to be an opamp and apply the feedback concept? Like source is the non-inv terminal and according to the virtual short concept of the opamp, the gate will try to copy the voltage of the source, and the transimpedance gain will be Rf? So, if the source is grounded, then it means that the gate will also be grounded.
But what I am confused is, if what I said is correct, then shorting the gate and the source terminal will turn off the transistor?
What am I missing here. Is my analysis of the working of the tia as a resistive feedback to the voltage amplifier opamp is correct? I will really appreciate if someone can explain or guide me the working of the common source tia?

The reference of the image is from the article: A. Atef, M. Atef, E. E. M. Khaled and M. Abbas, "CMOS Transimpedance Amplifiers for Biomedical Applications: A Comparative Study," in IEEE Circuits and Systems Magazine, vol. 20, no. 1, pp. 12-31, Firstquarter 2020, doi: 10.1109/MCAS.2019.2961724.
keywords: {Power demand;Medical devices;Biomedical monitoring;Pulse oximetry;Blood pressure measurement},

Yes, your approach of equivalence to opamp transimpedance amplifier has some merit. However a single mosfet has less open-loop gain than an op amp, so the idea of virtual ground at mosfet gate is less complete than the virtual ground of op amp transimpedance circuit. The mosfet must also be biased in an AC linear region, usually in saturation region..gate DC bias point is somewhat above threshold.

Hi thanks a lot for the reply. But, lets say I use a 3 stage amplifier to get a huge gain (I made it stable somehow using the miller cap), still the virtual short concept holds? Like I still don't understand is, if the virtual ground concept holds, it will take the transistor to cutoff?
